# Placing image in second column of two column page

Tags: spacing, floats, two-column

I would like to use a two column layout and have images and text in the second column begin at the top of the page and continue down with even spacing.  I've tried using the `multicol` package as well, but no luck.  LaTeX is spacing it so that the images are evenly distributed on the second page.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.5cm,vmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[justification=justified]{caption}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{10pt}
\showcolsendrule
\captionsetup{%
    singlelinecheck=false,
    tableposition=top,
    labelformat=empty,labelsep=none,skip=.1in
}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{\bfseries Name:    \\  Date: }

\chead{}
\rhead{\bfseries 6th Grade Math  \\   }
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{1) Find the area.}
\includegraphics[scale=.9]{/var/www/asymptote/pdf/parallelogram_a_3_1.pdf}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{2) Find the area.}
\includegraphics[scale=.9]{/var/www/asymptote/pdf/parallelogram_a_3_4.pdf}
\end{figure}

.....
```

The results are shown here:

[image]

Basically, I would like problem #8 shown in in the screenshot to be at the top of the second column, and any problems after #8 to be shown with even spacing below it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get the most out of this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things. You don't need floats (`figure`) and `\caption`.
Adjust the definition of `\problem` to suit.

Note that I didn't load `graphicx` because I don't have your images. Load it and, of course, remove the bogus definition of `\includegraphics` I added just for the example.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[includehead,top=2mm,bottom=1.5cm,hmargin=1.5cm,headheight=26pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\bfseries Name:    \\  Date: }
\fancyhead[R]{\bfseries 6th Grade Math  \\   }


\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

\newcommand{\problem}[2]{#1\par\nopagebreak\medskip#2\par\bigskip}

%%% just for this example
\newcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\rule{.3\columnwidth}{2cm}}


\begin{document}

\problem{1) Find the area.}
 {\includegraphics[scale=.9]{/var/www/asymptote/pdf/parallelogram_a_3_1.pdf}}

\problem{2) Find the area.}
 {\includegraphics[scale=.9]{/var/www/asymptote/pdf/parallelogram_a_3_4.pdf}}

\problem{3) Find the area.}
 {\includegraphics[scale=.9]{/var/www/asymptote/pdf/parallelogram_a_3_4.pdf}}

\problem{4) Find the area.}
 {\includegraphics[scale=.9]{/var/www/asymptote/pdf/parallelogram_a_3_4.pdf}}

\problem{5) Find the area.}
 {\includegraphics[scale=.9]{/var/www/asymptote/pdf/parallelogram_a_3_4.pdf}}

\problem{6) Find the area.}
 {\includegraphics[scale=.9]{/var/www/asymptote/pdf/parallelogram_a_3_4.pdf}}

\problem{7) Find the area.}
 {\includegraphics[scale=.9]{/var/www/asymptote/pdf/parallelogram_a_3_4.pdf}}

\problem{8) Find the area.}
 {\includegraphics[scale=.9]{/var/www/asymptote/pdf/parallelogram_a_3_4.pdf}}

\problem{9) Find the area.}
 {\includegraphics[scale=.9]{/var/www/asymptote/pdf/parallelogram_a_3_4.pdf}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
\usepackage{float}
```

to your preamble, and

```
\vspace*{1cm}
```

right after your last figure seems to work.